# Why doesn't subtraction sign work on while loop in php?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, sign, subtraction

```
<?php
$hp = 0;

while($hp < 50) {
    $flip = rand(0,2);
    if ($flip == 1) {
        echo "<p>X-Ray</p>";
        $hp += 15;
    } elseif ($flip == 2) {
        echo "<p>Special Move</p>";
        $hp += 10;

    } else {
        echo "<p>Punch</p>";
        $hp += 5;
    }
    echo "<p>Total so far: $hp</p>";
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

This is a PHP code. When I run it, it works fine. However, when I change it to this code below it doesn't.

```
<?php
$hp = 50;

while($hp > 1) {
    $flip = rand(0,2);
    if ($flip == 1) {
        echo "<p>X-Ray</p>";
        $hp -= 15;
    } elseif ($flip == 2) {
        echo "<p>Special Move</p>";
        $hp -= 10;

    } else {
        echo "<p>Punch</p>";
        $hp -= 5;
    }
    echo "<p>Total so far: $hp</p>";
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

Please help. tHE CHANGES I MADE ARE THE HIGHLIGHTED ONES.

Comment: What is this? `**-=**`. First Time Seeing Anything Like This.

Comment: there happened something with your code-formatting. if you use the code-sample button in the text editor, you don't need to use backticks anymore.

Comment: uh, you never assigned anything in the second version, so `$hp` starts as null, which willt est out as "less" than 1, therefore the loop never executes.

Comment: Sorry. that was printing mistake. I did write $hp=50; however, it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You never created `$hp` properly in the second version:

```
50;
```

doesn't do anything. It just tells php "here, have a 50", and php goes "gee, thanks, ok, whatever" and moves onwards. Then you have

```
while($hp > 1) {
```

Since `$hp` is undefined, it's null, and the code parses/executes as:

```
while($hp > 1) {
while(null > 1) {
while(0 > 1) {
FALSE -> exit loop
```

Comment: Sorry. that was printing mistake. I did write $hp=50; however, it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your second code sample (after your changes) works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question, what if i want to write "you have killed him" instead of "Total so far: 5", when $hp becomes less than 1?

Answer (score 0):

You never created $hp properly in the second version:

`50;`

If you do change it to $hp = 50;

Comment: Sorry. that was printing mistake. I did write $hp=50; however, it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: When i run the code it runs fine for me and prints out the following.. `Punch

Total so far: 45

X-Ray

Total so far: 30

Punch

Total so far: 25

Punch

Total so far: 20

X-Ray

Total so far: 5

X-Ray

Total so far: -10`

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question, what if i want to write "you have killed him" instead of "Total so far: 5", when $hp becomes less than 1?

Comment: You would just replace the 'Total so far' statement to this
`echo "<p>you have killed him</p>";`